# Why is my contact form not working?

Tags: forms, contact

Im new to Wordpress but have been tinkering with a website for my upcomming bussines.
I have run into some problems here And there, but have been managing most things in an acceptabele way.

But, i Just cant get my contact form to actually send me the emails...
My website is : www.hondtel.be hosted at one.com

Screenshots of the contact form setup supplied in this post.
What am i doing wrong here?[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: Does your server provide php mail function or sendmail or perhaps only smtp mail is available. A simple php file containing phpinfo(); or phpinfo(INFO_MODULES); might give you more information.

Comment: Hey could you send me a PM Explaining how to exactly do this? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how to send a PM on here. All you need do is create a file called phpinfo.php in your website folder and paste this code into it. <?php phpinfo(); phpinfo(INFO_MODULES); ?> and save it. Then load it in your web browser http://yourwebsite.com/phpinfo.php and you should see the info.  Make sure you delete the file later so hackers don't benefit from the info it provides.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks a lot for the assistance!

Comment: what was the problem. If you have resolved it you should post an answer explaining what the issue was so future visitors might benefit from it.